# Check for inf - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

What is the method for testing whether a double (or integer) is infinity, for example when 1/0 operation is performed?

isfinite(n) does not seem to work.

Comment: An integer cannot be infinity.

Comment: You could test `x * 2 == x && x != 0` or something like that... For NaN you can test `x != x`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "`isfinite( )` does not seem to work."?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You may check

```
if(d == INFINITY) {}
```

or

```
if(d > DBL_MAX) {}
```

`INFINITY` is a constant float expression defined in `math.h` representing positive infinity; 
`DBL_MAX` is a constant defined in `float.h` representing the largest double that can be represented.

Check also [here](http://www.johndcook.com/IEEE_exceptions_in_cpp.html)

Comment: You should probably describe where those symbols come from for this answer to be useful.

Comment: Note: these tests only check for positive infinity, not negative infinity.

Comment: Answer is accepted and highly voted up but it isn't fully correct. Question asks about checking for infinity. But DBL_MAX is not the same as INFINITY. The first condition in the answer is correct. Second one is not.

Comment: @ValeriyVan Afaics there's no way a double can be larger than `DBL_MAX` but different from `INFINITY`

Comment: @Saphrosit, Debugging I was trying catch overflow comparing value against DBL_MAX. And failed. That's how I now know that except of DBL_MAX we have INFINITY and they are not equal.

Comment: @ValeriyVan yes, they are not equal, `INFINITY` > `DBL_MAX`. Not sure what your test was (and not sure whether there are very particular cases where this check may fail)