# how to compare if float variable value is infinite?

Tags: ios, variables, floating-point, compare, infinite

debugger says me float value is inf

I just see in debug window section of xcode is this

floatVar1=(float)inf

inf means infinite ?

so how can I compare it ?

something like this:

if (floatVar1==INFITINE){
  [self doBlah];
}

Comment: This has already been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302983/check-for-inf-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should work, though it's not objective-c put plain c:

```
if(isinf(floatVar1)) { ... }
```

Also, you need to include `math.h`. For more info see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/isinf/

Answer (score 2):

To test whether a value is either positive infinity or negative infinity:

```
if (isinf(floatVar1)) …
```

To test only whether a value is positive infinity:

```
if (floatVar1 == INFINITY) …
```

In either case, use `#include <math.h>`.